# Is XSP suitable for Internet facing, production hosts? (either self hosted, as an Apache plugin, or FastCGI)

Tags: linux, macos, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[XSP](https://github.com/mono/xsp) is portable version of ASP.NET that allows for operation on OSX, Linux, and Windows.  It's an alternative to IIS, and hosts its own web server, or can plug into existing web servers such as Apache.

- What deployment methodology of XSP offers the most security?
- Are there technical differences in the deployment options that would affect security?

I'm asking because I'm writing server side software that will need to run on multiple platforms and I want to find a webhost that can run on any platform and provide robust security